# How to sonfigure setting of jenkins throught Jekin API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

with help of jenkink stoken anad user wants to get the detial of the configurew setting with an api code in python

import requests

def get_jenkins_user_settings(username, jenkins_url, api_token):
# Construct the URL for the Jenkins API endpoint
api_url = f"{jenkins_url}/user/{username}/api/json"

```
# Set up the authentication credentials
auth = (username, api_token)

try:
    # Make a GET request to the Jenkins API
    response = requests.get(api_url, auth=auth)

    # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        user_settings = response.json()
        print(f"Full Name: {user_settings['fullName']}")
        
        # Check if 'property' key exists and has elements
        if 'property' in user_settings and user_settings['property']:
            user_properties = user_settings['property']

            # Check if 'address' key exists in the first element of 'property'
            if 'address' in user_properties[0]:
                print(f"Email: {user_properties[0]['address']}")
            else:
                print("Email not found in user properties.")
        else:
            print("User properties not found.")

    else:
        print(f"Failed to get user settings. Status Code: {response.status_code}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

## Call the function to get user settings

get_jenkins_user_settings(username, jenkins_url, token)

Error:
NO property need to check the Enable Matrix-Based Security is active
Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Authorization

need to call the api it should return json and a poroiperty which relstes to manage security

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please try to correct the spelling mistakes - for example **detial** should be **detail**, right? Also use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your [python] code.